# extracting related models from the params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a many to many polymorphic relationship:

```
class DocumentTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :document, polymorphic: true
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents, through: :document_tasks
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, though: :document_tasks, as: :document    
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, through: :document_tasks, as: :document
end
```

I have a URL that looks like this that sends information to the server:

```
/contacts/1/tasks?status_id_is=1&user_id_is=1
```

But sometimes it can look like this (since there is a polymorphic relationship):

```
/services/1/tasks?status_id_is=1&user_id_is=1
```

In my controller, I need to get the object of that polymorphic relationship. Typically, I can do the following:

```
document_id = params.detect {|name,_| name =~ /(.+)_id/}
@document = document_id[0].gsub("_id","").capitalize.constantize.find(document_id[1])
```

However, when the url contains a query string, this won't work because status_id_is and user_id_is will match the regular expression. An obvious solution would be to change the regex to `/^(.+)_id$/` but who knows how many other use cases may arise.

Is there a nice way to achieve what I want? For example, something in the request object like `request.association_parameter` or `params.association_parameter`.

Comment: what are `status_id_is` and `user_id_is`? Are they referring to the `document` object's `status_id` and `user_id` attributes? Equivalently, I am asking if all of Task, Contact, and Service models have `status_id` and `user_id` attributes in which you are intending to filter with those params.

Comment: status_id_is and user_id_is are just filter parameters related to tasks. They have nothing to do with documents.None of the models have status_id or user_id attributes. At the same time, I am hoping for a flexible solution that won't break easy. A cheap solution would be to use a regex like /^(.+)_id$/ but who knows, it might break later on down the road.

Comment: I haven't seen `.detect` being used with two arguments in the {} block. What does it do? Just so I could understand what the code is trying to do.

Comment: It returns an array like ["contact_id", 1]

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. This seems to be a good question. `routes.rb` is not reliable in this context because `MODEL_id` conflicts with your detect regex, unless you manually specify that other more complete regex of yours. I have an idea, although I'd like to also know if any others have another approach. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For filtering on a collection--like a search or the params you have to filter tasks--I can suggest an alternative approach which is to use `params[:q]` instead for filtering.

This is in line with "some" conventions for API filtering, like how `ransack` (gem) and ElasticSearch use `q` or `query` params, which is a wrapper param for scoping.

Equivalently, if following this approach, yours will look like below

```
/contacts/1/tasks?q[status_id_is]=1&q[user_id_is]=1
```

In this way, you will now have no problems looping in your `params.detect` because the `status_id_is` and `user_id_is` will be inside params[:q] and therefore is one-level deeper in the hash, which the `params.detect` loop will already no longer take into account. Thus any `MODEL_id` params will work for the polymorphic route.

Comment: You mentioned "conventions for API filtering". Are these conventions documented anywhere? Such as using :q?

Comment: Ohh you're right, technically speaking I should have said, "their" convention of using a param wrapper like "q" or "query". I haven't looked into it yet if using a wrapper param is indeed a convention in filtering. If anyone knows or finds out, please inform me to satisfy my curiosity.